# Assign this to self for every class method for accessing object?

Tags: javascript, jquery, callback, this

If we are creating class methods which uses lots of callbacks like jQuery functions, what would be a good way to access object itself (this) in the methods? Do I need to assign this to a var for every class method?

Example:

```
 var myClass = function(){};
 myClass.prototype = {
    myFunc : function(){
       var self = this;
       // uses self in callbacks
    }
}
```

Comment: yes or use arrow functions...

Comment: Class in JS (ES5) is a constructor function. But you are creating an object. You can't use `new` on it.

Comment: I changed the class to function. So before ES5's arrow function, this would need to be repeated for each method?